# Android subTitle show array count error

Tags: android, count, subtitle

I have created an `ArrayList` with count

```
 private ArrayList<GeoJsonResponse> localGeoJsonResponse;
FeatureCollection featureCollection;
GeoJsonResponse data = null;
Integer number = localGeoJsonResponse.size();
String str = Integer.toString(number);
String event= str + " total event";
```

I have to set a value of the count on sub title of action bar and this is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_color)));
    ab.setTitle(R.string.mappa);
    ab.setSubtitle(event);
```

I receive an error when i call this view. In the setSubtitle I can set only  `String`, example

```
ab.setSubtitle("events");
```

rest of the view works well.
Any help please?
Thanks

this is the log of error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.###.###.###.MyMapActivity.onCreate(MyMapActivity.java:164)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at
```

thanks

Comment: Did you initialize the list?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible places in your code where **NullPointerException** may occur:

1. Your **localGeoJsonResponse** wasn't initialised but you call

   ```
   localGeoJsonResponse.size(); -> which may result in null pointer
   ```

   You have to do as @Teodor Liv's answer:

   ```
   ArrayList<GeoJsonResponse> localGeoJsonResponse = new ArrayList<GeoJsonResponse>();
   ```
2. Another one is that you don't really get the ActionBar object, so when you call:

   ```
   ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); -> This may cause null pointer
   ```

   For checking, you can do like this:

   ```
   ActionBar ab = getAcionBar();
   if (ab != null) {
       ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
       ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
       ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_color)));
       ab.setTitle(R.string.mappa);
       ab.setSubtitle(event);
   } else {
       Log.e(TAG, "fail to get ActionBar");
   }
   ```